# Returning a value from OnGet action method back to razor page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, razor-pages

I have a select tag which onchange is going to an OnGet action with a stored procedure inside of it.I want to be able to get whatever values is being returned by that stored procedure and return it to another select tag.

When I debug, the onchange goes to the OnGet action, but for whatever reason it is not getting the value. I'm using a ajax method to get to the server side and call the OnGet action. I've tried to do a test alert to see if I'll be able to get the data but still not able to do so.

**My select tag**

```
//First select on change
<select id="driverselect" asp-for="TripNumber.UserDriverID" asp-items="Model.UserDrivers" class="form-control">
     <option value="">Select a driver</option>
 </select>

//Second select where value from stored procedure should go
<select id="vehicleselect" asp-for="TripNumber.VehicleType" asp-items="Model.VehicleList" class="form-control">
     <option value="">Select a vehicle</option>
</select>
```

**My jquery ajax**

```
$("#driverselect").on("change", function () {                
      $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: '@Url.Page("TripTicketEntry","OnGetVehicleAssign")',
           contentType: 'application/json',
           data: { UserDriverID : UserDriverID },
           success: function (data) {
              alert(data.test);
           }
       });
});
```

**My OnGet action**

```
 public IActionResult OnGetVehicleAssign(int UserDriverID)
    {
        //var param = new SqlParameter("@UserDriverID", UserDriverID);
        //var VehicleAssign = _context.VehicleAssign.FromSql("uspVehicleAssign @UserDriverID", param).ToList();

        //TripNumber = new TripNumber();
        //TripNumber.VehicleType = VehicleAssign.FirstOrDefault().Type;

        //return Page();

        var result = new { test = "test" };

        return new JsonResult(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the selected `UserDriverID` to server side :

```
data: { UserDriverID: $("#driverselect").val() },
```